# Insertion and Deletion in list <string>

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++

I am currently writing a small program to insert or delete a row in a list of string read from an input text file.

This is my code

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <list>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    list <string> buffer;
    string fileName = "input.txt";
    ifstream file(fileName);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        string line;
        while (getline(file, line))
        {
            //store each line in the buffer
            buffer.push_back(line);
        }
    }
    list<string>::const_iterator it;
    it = buffer.begin();
    int position = 1;
    for (int n = 0; n < position; ++n)
    {
        ++it;
    }
    string input("This is a new line");
    buffer.insert(it, 1, input);
    //I can then use erase function to delete a line

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The buffer list has

```
This is line 1
This is line 2
This is line 3
This is line 4
```

I want to know if there are other ways (maybe more efficient) to insert or delete a line in the buffer. Thank you!

Comment: Please post the actual code - what you have posted cannot possibly compile.

Comment: @NeilButterworth I updated my code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several versions of `list<>::insert()`.  One of them inserts a single element, so you can replace this:

```
buffer.insert(it, 1, input);
```

with:

```
buffer.insert(it, input);
```

---

You can also use `list<>::emplace()` to create the string in place :

```
buffer.emplace(it, "This is a new line");
```

---

You can simplify this:

```
list<string>::const_iterator it;
it = buffer.begin();
int position = 1;
for (int n = 0; n < position; ++n)
{
    ++it;
}
```

to:

```
auto it = buffer.begin();
advance(it, 1);
```

Comment: In fact, I cannot use `buffer.insert(it, input);` because my program won't compile. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: @Coded-BloodJunior, it's in C++11 (with `const_iterator`).  The same goes for `list<>::emplace()`.  Maybe your compiler has options to use C++11 or later ?